# Laravel Invoice & InvoiceItems - How to Update?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.7

I'm using `Laravel 5.7` & `VueJs 2.5.*` ...

I have two table `TicketInvoice` & `TicketInvoiceItems`, with a relation like, `TicketInvoice` hasMany `TicketInvoiceItems` & `TicketInvoiceItems` belongsTo `TicketInvoice`...

I can successfully create `TicketInvoice` & `TicketInvoiceItems`, **but i don't know how to update it...**

**Here is my `store` method (Working):**

```php
    public function store(Request $request)
    {   
        $ticketInvoiceItems = collect();

        foreach($request['ticketInvoiceItems'] as $invoiceItem) {
        $ticketInvoiceItems->push(new TicketInvoiceItems ([
            'passenger_name' => $invoiceItem ['passenger_name'],
            'ticket_no' => $invoiceItem ['ticket_no'],
            'fares' => $invoiceItem ['fares'],
            'sub_total' => $invoiceItem ['sub_total']
        ]));
        }

        $ticketInvoice = TicketInvoice::create([
            'vendor_id' => $request['vendor_id'],
            'ticket_invoice_no' => $request['ticket_invoice_no'],
            'ticket_invoice_date' => $request['ticket_invoice_date'],
            'ticket_invoice_fares_total' => $request['ticket_invoice_fares_total'],
            'ticket_invoice_grand_total' => $request['ticket_invoice_grand_total'],
        ]);

        $ticketInvoice->ticketInvoiceItems()->saveMany($ticketInvoiceItems);
    }
```

**Here is my `update` method (Not-Working :'( ):**

```php
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $ticketInvoice = TicketInvoice::findOrFail($id);

        $ticketInvoiceItems = collect();

        foreach($request['ticketInvoiceItems'] as $invoiceItem) {
            $ticketInvoiceItems->push(new TicketInvoiceItems ([
                'passenger_name' => $invoiceItem ['passenger_name'],
                'ticket_no' => $invoiceItem ['ticket_no'],
                'fares' => $invoiceItem ['fares'],
                'sub_total' => $invoiceItem ['sub_total']
            ]));
            }
            $ticketInvoice->update($request->all());
            $ticketInvoice->ticketInvoiceItems()->update($ticketInvoiceItems);

    }
```

Comment: Do you want to override all the TicketInvoiceItems?

Comment: you can delete previously saved items and create new one from request

Comment: @HCK Yeah something like that, Like user enter wrong fares and he want to correct it by updating Invoice or user forgot to add some items in invoice so edit the invoice add items and update it.

Comment: @SaurabhMistry Bro just need to edit and update the invoice.

Comment: do this : `$ticketInvoice->ticketInvoiceItems()->delete();
        $ticketInvoice->ticketInvoiceItems()->saveMany($ticketInvoiceItems);` ;

Comment: not working how?  What isn't happening?  Any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, deleted child records:

```php
    $ticketInvoice->ticketInvoiceItems()->delete();
```

Then store the new ones:

```php
    $ticketInvoiceItems = collect();

    foreach($request['ticketInvoiceItems'] as $invoiceItem) {
        $ticketInvoiceItems->push(new TicketInvoiceItems ([
            'passenger_name' => $invoiceItem ['passenger_name'],
            'ticket_no' => $invoiceItem ['ticket_no'],
            'fares' => $invoiceItem ['fares'],
            'sub_total' => $invoiceItem ['sub_total']
        ]));
    }

    $ticketInvoice->ticketInvoiceItems()->saveMany($ticketInvoiceItems);
```